# Format exception String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datetime-format

```
objTour.tourStartDate = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(
        DateTime.ParseExact(txtTourStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
            .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

where `txtTourStartDate.Text="16/08/2012"`.

I have searched and read all posts related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [custom date format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), `/` denotes the culture-specific date separator, not the literal character `/`. Thus, the result of your code depends on the user's (or the server's) localization settings.

To make your code independent of culture-specific settings, you have two options:

- Explicitly specify a culture that uses a slash as the date separator, e.g.

  ```
  DateTime.ParseExact(txtTourStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  ```
- or escape the character, e.g.

  ```
  DateTime.ParseExact(txtTourStartDate.Text, @"dd\/MM\/yyyy", null)
  ```

  (note the `@` *and* the `\`).

Both should yield the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

This will be enough:

```
objTour.tourStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTourStartDate.Text, 
                                            "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: OMG, I just realized what that guy is doing (Parse -> ToString -> ToDateTime). You are right, of course, +1. I'll keep my answer here, though, anyway, since not escaping `/` is *another* thing that he's doing wrong.

Comment: When I saw the question, I really had to wonder how he got to doing that that way.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code works, although you are doing lot of unnecessary conversions. *(DateTime -> ToString -> ToDateTime)*, the **real issue** is `InvariantCulture`. Since you are passing `null` for `CultureInfo` try `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Your original code:

```
objTour.tourStartDate = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(
        DateTime.ParseExact(txtTourStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

A better one could be:

```
objTour.tourStartDate =
DateTime.ParseExact(txtTourStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```