# Format Exception - string not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an issue similar to this > [Format exception String was not recognized as a valid DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209436/format-exception-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

However, my spec requires a date format of ddMMyyyy, therefore I have modified my code but I am still getting the same error

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(now.ToString(), @"ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am unclear why.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a date to a string and then parse it again as a date? A DateTime is stored without format, you format it only when you output it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code fails because you are attempting to parse a date in the format `ddMMyyyy`, when by default `DateTime.ToString()` will produce a format with both date and time in the current culture. 
For myself in Australia that would be `dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss p` e.g. `11/10/2013 11:07:03 AM`

You must realise is that the DateTime object actually stores a date as individual components (e.g. day, month, year) that only needs to be format when you output the value into whatever format you desire.
E.g.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string formattedDate = now.ToString("ddMMyyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

For more information see the api doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For `ParseExact` to work, the string coming in must match exactly the pattern matching.  In the other question you mentioned, the text was coming from a web form where the format was specified to be exactly one format.

In your case you generated the date using `DateTime.Now.ToString()` which will not be in the format `ddMMyyyy`.  If you want to make the date round trip, you need to specify the format both places:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(now.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), @"ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug your code and look at what the result of `now.ToString()` is, it's is not in the format of "ddMMyyyy", which is why the parse is failing. If you want to output `now` as a string in the ddMMyyy format, then try now.ToSTring("ddMMyyyy") instead.

Answer (score 1):

now.ToString() does not return a string formatted in that way.  Try using now.ToString("ddMMyyyy").
You might be better off testing with a static string like "30041999"